# javascript not working in dotnetnuke

Tags: javascript, asp.net, dotnetnuke

i have a javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
function getFaq(selectedFaq)
{
 document.frmFaqs.S1.value = selectedFaq;
}
```

ascx is

```
    <script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
    alert("asds");

    function getFaq(selectedFaq)
    {
   <asp:Literal id="litScript" runat="server" />
    }
    </script>
    </head>
   <body> 
   <form action="" name="frmFaqs">        
   <div runat="server" id="wrapper">
    </div>          
    </form>
 </body>
```

ascx.cs is

```
   protected void Page_Load(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        FAQController obj = new FAQController();
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        int id = 1;
        ds = obj.getfaq(id);
        litScript.Text += "{document.frmFaqs.S1.value = selectedFaq;}";
        string ltr;
        ltr = "<tr>";
        ltr += "<td height='52' valign='top' width='100%'>";
        ltr += "<table style='border-collapse: collapse;' id='AutoNumber1' border='0' bordercolor='#111111' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' height='1' width='100%'>";
        ltr += "<tbody>";
        ltr += "<tr><td align='center' height='42' width='34%'>&nbsp;</td><td align='center' height='42' width='33%'><p align='left'><font color='#0000FF' face='Verdana'>Question</font></p></td><td align='center' height='42' width='33%'>&nbsp;</td> </tr>";
        ltr += "<tr><td align='center' height='37' width='34%'>&nbsp;</td><td align='center' height='37' width='33%'><p align='left'><select size='16' name='cmbFaqs' style='width:400;height:146' onchange='getFaq(frmFaqs.cmbFaqs.options[frmFaqs.cmbFaqs.selectedIndex].value);  return false' multiple='multiple'><option selected='selected'>Select Your Question</option>";
        for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            if (i == 0)
            {
                ltr += "<option>-----" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["heading"].ToString() + "-----</option>";
                Session["temp"] = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["heading"].ToString();
                ltr += "<option value='" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["answer"].ToString() + "'>" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["questions"].ToString() + " </option>";
            }
            else if (Session["temp"].ToString() == ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["heading"].ToString())
            {
                ltr += "<option value='" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["answer"].ToString() + "'>" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["questions"].ToString() + " </option>";
            }
            else
            {
                ltr += "<option>-----" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["heading"].ToString() + "-----</option>";
                Session["temp"] = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["heading"].ToString();
                ltr += "<option value='" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["answer"].ToString() + "'>" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["questions"].ToString() + " </option>";
            }
        }
        ltr += "</select></p></td><td align='center' height='37' width='33%'>&nbsp;</td></tr>";
        ltr += "<tr><td align='center' height='44' width='34%'>&nbsp;</td><td align='center' height='44' width='33%'><p align='left'><font color='#0000FF' face='Verdana'>Answer <font size='2'>(Do not type in this box)</font></font></p></td><td align='center' height='44' width='33%'>&nbsp;</td></tr>";
        ltr += " <tr><td align='center' width='34%'><font style='font-size: 9pt' face='Arial'><br>&nbsp;</font></td><td align='center' width='33%'><p align='left'><textarea rows='2' name='S1' cols='20' style='width: 400px; height: 247px;'>Unfortunately,we are not qualified to answer questions authoritively on Islam and therefore refrain from doing so in order not to mislead. We are only able to answer questions on our products. Please redirect your question to &lt;A target='_blank'";
        ltr += "href='http://english.islamweb.net/ver2/Fatwa/index.php?lang=E'&gt;http://english.islamweb.net/ver2/Fatwa/index.php?lang=E&lt;/A&gt;or &lt;a href='http://www.askimam.com'&gt;www.askimam.com&lt;/a&gt;</textarea></p></td><td align='center' width='33%'>&nbsp; </td></tr>";
        ltr += "</tbody>";
        ltr += "</table>";
        ltr += "</td>";
        ltr += "</tr>";
        wrapper.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(ltr));

    }
```

it works perfectly when i used it in an .aspx page.but when i tried it in a usercontrol in dotnet nuke,javascript is not working

NOTE:frmFaqs is a form with runat=server ...how can i use form tag in dotnetnuke

Comment: Can you post the .ascx so we can see what you're working with?  You probably just need to use the ClientID of the form.

Comment: i hve done most of it in code itself...i l put both ascx and ascx.cs

Answer (score 4):

DotNetNuke wraps everything in a form, your code cannot have its own forms.  If you need a form, you'll need to use an iframe, or dynamically (with JavaScript) move/create it outside of the main form.

Comment: What sort of error are you getting?  Is there a JavaScript error in the console?  Does the page send a post, but not update anything?  What is the content of the iframe (i.e. what is being loaded there?  a plain HTML page?)